Passing information from one SSR Blazor page to another (preferably without using query strings in the URL)
Inside of Blazor .NET Core 8, using Authentication, I go from my Home.razor page to the Login.Razor page. If I have stored any information in a class in Home.razor that informatoin is lost the minute I load Login.razor.
I could pass the information I need in Login.razor using a query string in the URL and just have Blazor parse the string, but means that information is showing to the user. That isn't good for security purposes. I would rather pass information to Login.razor in another way.
Essentially I have a global theme I would like to pass along for each web page to use. It's a bootstrap css file name. It's just a string, but perhaps in the future I may need to pass more than just a string, I may need to pass a whole class.

Each request for a page in SSR is standalone.  The only way you know that a request for Login came from Home is if it contains some type of token to provide that information.  If you want some sort of session based application then go interactive, not SSR.

Just create a singleton service (if you have the user info) or a scoped service that stores this information. Retrieve it in the layout.

As you need to pass information for each page, I think the best way using cookie. That will be good when you are using pure SSR. Because only in SSR, HttpContext would be available which allows you to set and read cookies.You could try following sample to set and read data in SSR.
@page "/"
@using System.Text.Json

<form id="form1" method="post" @onsubmit="SetData" @formname="form1">
    <AntiforgeryToken></AntiforgeryToken>
    <button type="submit" form="form1">save data</button>
</form>

<form id="form2" method="post" @onsubmit="ReadData" @formname="form2">
    <AntiforgeryToken></AntiforgeryToken>
    <button type="submit" form="form2">read data</button>
</form>

<form id="form3" method="post" @onsubmit="ClearData" @formname="form3">
    <AntiforgeryToken></AntiforgeryToken>
    <button type="submit" form="form3">clear data</button>
</form>

info1:@info.info1<br />
Theme:@info.theme<br />

@code{
    private Info info { get; set; } = new();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ReadData();
    }


    [CascadingParameter]
    HttpContext httpContext { get; set; }
    private void SetData(){

        var newinfo = new Info { info1 = "myinfo", theme = "mytheme" };
        var jsonString = JsonSerializer.Serialize(newinfo);    
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("info",jsonString);
    }
    private void ReadData()
    {
        var jsonString = httpContext.Request.Cookies["info"];
        if (jsonString != null)
        {
            info = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Info>(jsonString);
        }
    }

    private void ClearData()
    {
        httpContext.Response.Cookies.Delete("info");
        info = new();
    }
    public class Info{
        public string info1 { get; set; } 
        public string theme { get; set; }
    }
}

If you want to interactive without too much http, you could try use javascipt. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/static-server-rendering?view=aspnetcore-8.0
